# Unable to access Controller Annotation data from Spring Controller

Tags: reflection, controller, metadata

I am developing a Maven plugin which generates some application metadata related to Spring Controllers. Currently I am unable to get the "Controller" annotation (with its "value" property) of my spring controllers so I am kinda stuck...
[image: "analyzedClass" is the class instance from my Spring Controllers]

How could I get this annotation and its value ?. Thankx

Comment: Just to clarify... The "isControllerAnnotationAvailable" is always false... But when I execute the same code inside my webapp, it works like charm... Inside my plugin, I take up special attention to load all the necessary dependencies... But anyway, I keep getting a "false" value...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Thankx to all !. This could did it !!!.]

This code let me get the desired values. Thankx to all